# Cython: How to convert numpy 2D array of type "object" to memoryview?

Tags: numpy, cython, memoryview

I am wondering how one can convert a 2D numpy array input of type "object" into a Cython memoryview?

For example, if I have the following Cython extension type:

```
cdef class A:
   cdef:
       const double[:, ::1] X  # here I define that X is a memoryview

   cdef int init(self, object X):
        # how do I convert X into the correct memoryview object?
        self.X = X
```

In Python, the class `A` is initialized:

```
def do_something():
    # say we have a 2D numpy array; this is an example, and not necessarily how it is constructed
    X = np.zeros((5, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    A()
    
    # When we initialize, I would like Cython to now store it as a Cython memoryview
    A.init(X)
```

There are two issues I face with the Cython code currently:

1. I don't know whether or not `X` is initialized as contiguous, or fortran.
2. I want to force it into a contiguous array.

How do I make it so that way I can just work with Cython code that is always working with a contiguous array?

A tangential question I would have is are there any tradeoffs to forcing the Cython memoryview to be contiguous vs fortran?

Comment: That array contains references to Python objects.  Unless you can find something in the `cython` docs about that kind of array, I doubt if it can be cast as a memoryview.  Note that defined the memory view as containing `double`, not python references.  What are you trying to do with this array?  What is its source? and what does it contain?

Comment: You can have `object[:,:]` memoryviews if you want. They won't be as fast as a c typed memoryview though

Comment: @hpaulj and @DavidW sorry I have updated the question to provide more clarification. The `X` is meant to be a 2D numpy array that is passed in from "somewhere in Python". My impression is that I need the `object` to specify that it is coming from Python, but I want to force it into a Cython contiguous memoryview. Lmk if that is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it so that way I can just work with Cython code that is always working with a contiguous array?

[`numpy.ascontiguousarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html#numpy-ascontiguousarray) - it'll do nothing if it's already right and make a copy if it isn't.

> A tangential question I would have is are there any tradeoffs to forcing the Cython memoryview to be contiguous vs fortran?

For best use of the CPU cache you usually want the innermost loop to be over the contiguous dimension. Which you prefer therefore depends on what you're doing. For example, for a `matrix vector` matrix multiplication you likely want the second dimension to be contiguous. For a `vector matrix` multiplication you likely want the first dimension to be contiguous.

If you're passing them to third party libraries you may well want to match what they expect.

---

Maybe if you're accepting arrays from a variety of sources the correct memoryview is `double[:,:]` (i.e. not requiring it to be contiguous)?

Comment: Sorry a follow-on question regarding this that I could not find in the Cython docs is "Is there any performance differences for typing `[:, :]` vs e.g. `[:, ::1]`, or `[::1, :]`?" If not, is the main reason for explicitly typing it that way to prevent errors from passing in say a Fortran array to a function expecting a contiguous array?

Comment: Using a `[:, ::1]` or `[::1, :]` definitely has a performance advantage because you don't have to look up and calculate the strides of the contiguous dimension at runtime.